# How can I restrict apps from using WiFi?

Tags: iphone, network, wifi

As we know that we can "use mobile data for" a particular app so WhatsApp for instance can be allowed to use mobile data while other apps can't.

How can I accomplish the same for WiFi data use?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion of why Apple did this or site scope; this discussion is highly encouraged on [meta] and where I [moved it to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66047/discussion-on-question-by-deepak-how-can-i-restrict-apps-from-using-wifi).

Answer (score 1):

There is no ios level switch for preventing WiFi or USB tethered  data connections on a per app basis. Disabling WiFi you don’t trust is the first step.

The next practical method to do this is control the network with firewalls, proxies and DNS / routing to block whatever access patterns you need to control or monitor.

Unless the specific app has a sign off / sign out/ disable feature or configuration option, deleting the app entirely is the last lever available if you cannot control the network.

Comment: heads-up: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375687/how-to-know-if-an-ios-app-cannot-access-the-internet?noredirect=1&lq=1 this suggests that iOS 13 brought the feature, to most apps.

Comment: @ankii Curious - I'm missing how that would let App A use WiFi and App B not use WiFi on the same phone that's connected to WiFi.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375687/how-to-know-if-an-ios-app-does-not-access-the-internet-via-wifi-or-cellular?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment505781_375688 It's for bluetooth additionally. Not yet for Wi-Fi Also, OP didn't ping you there.