# How to know if an iOS app does not access the internet via Wi-Fi or Cellular?

Tags: ios, wifi, security, privacy, cellular-data

Is there a clear indicator that an app does not access the internet via Wi-Fi or cellular?

For instance in the Settings App there is an entry for every app installed on iOS 13. There you find an app specific toggle for „cellular data“. But some apps (eg KeePassium) do not have this toggle.

Would an app connect to the internet if its “cellular data” setting is missing?   Because every other app that can use Wi-Fi and cellular has that toggle. I am not worried about bluetooth tethering as I can turn off Bluetooth on individual app basis and cable tethering is not an issue.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199695/restrict-certain-apps-from-using-wi-fi-internet-on-ios-8

Comment: Thanks pkamb the question is connected but not really answering mine.

Comment: I'm not understanding how tethering applies here. More fundamentally what does "access the internet" for you in one or two specific app/network situations? Basically, if the Phone can access internet - your app gets traffic routed however it asks. Are you instead backing into a question looking for how WiFi / Cellular / low usage modes work in general?

Comment: The phone could be tethered to another device via cable or Bluetooth and use the internet of the other device. But these are scenarios I am not really interested in. Someone else added this tag. I am most interested in the „missing cellular data toggle“ case. Is that an indicator that the app does not access WiFi or cellular in any way?

Answer (score 1):

*iOS 12*. 
There's Wi-Fi, Bluetooth and USB-Tethering that you cannot directly toggle if you're using any of those interfaces for any purpose. Only way to stop them is to turn off the connection path itself. For Wi-Fi and Bluetooth, they should be turned off globally in Settings. For USB, detaching the cable is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yeah I did not think about usb tethering. Bluetooth you can control via the permission. But do you know if WiFi cannot be used when there is no “ allow cellular data” toggle in settings?

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant. which Bluetooth permission do you mean? I only know of the turn on/ off bluetooth globally in settings. Same for Wi-Fi. Also, edit your post to clarify what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: In the Settings App there is an entry for every app installed. There you find an app specific toggle for Bluetooth and „cellular data“.

Comment: @ChristophPacher I've seen only Cellular in individual app settings so far on iOS 12.4. Wi-Fi and bluetooth are globally controlled.

Comment: there is a toggle for Bluetooth on iOS 13

Answer (score 0):

If you go to settings and cellular you can see all applications that use internet over 4G, how many data they used and stop them to use cellular data

Comment: I have a feeling you did not read or did not understand the question I posted.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, the first comment to the question reveals the easiest way. That applies though if your device is jailbroken. Cydia (now being replaced by Sileo) offers maybe even several tweaks for such purposes.

Thу other way around is to reveal weather your app uses internet by yourself. To be honest I am not familiar with the app, but if it is supposed to use internet you can try to determine its internet access by switching Wi-Fi (or cellular) off while using the app.

Comment: I don’t want to jail break. The app is supposed to not access the internet so no possibility to test.

Comment: I was proposing options. Question did not say, that jailbreak is not an option in this case. In that case my answer to the question is just no.